# how can i make the android sdk a first class dependency in bazel?

Tags: bazel

I dislike having to download and maintain the Android SDK outside of my Bazel workspace. It seems like it could and should be a first class dependency within Bazel itself, managed in WORKSPACE (or Bzlmod).

I found one [GitHub project](https://github.com/quittle/bazel_android_sdk_downloader) that appears to be doing just that, but it's not been updated in years. Has there been any other effort on this front, or is everyone just resigned to being herded continually toward Android Studio?

Comment: "Rants in disguise" or "why" questions are generally off-topic here, as are requests for an off-site resource (like a modern/maintained equivalent to the project linked) -- Stack Overflow is narrowly and specifically focused on questions with answers that are expected to _change how you go about the practice of software development_.

Comment: I absolutely want to change the way I go about the practice of software development. I do not want to use Android Studio. Ever. I want the freedom to develop for Android how I want to. I want the ability to have a hermetic Android SDK, not be at the whims of whatever version it has installed this week. Perhaps this is a rant, but it is also very much a desire for change. Update: But I take something from your point, and modified the title to be less rant, and more actionable.

Comment: Agreed, this is a much better title; close vote retracted. (I think the question is whether the expectation is that the question will _persuade other people to change something outside Stack Overflow_, in which case it's probably not on-topic, or the question can be reasonably expected to provide an answer that lets you adjust your own practices, in which case it's probably on-topic; now it's at least asking for the latter).